# Amazon SdkClientException during file upload in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Attaching code snippet for uploading a file in s3 bucket**

public TransferManager transferManager() {
return TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(this.awss3Template.getAmazonS3())
.withMultipartUploadThreshold((long) (5 * 1024 * 1025)).build();
}

Upload upload = transferManager().upload(this.awss3Template.getBucket(), keyName, file.getInputStream(), metadata);

**aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.940**

**we are getting the below exception during upload**

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Upload canceled
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:137) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.940.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:45) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.940.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_312]

Note: This exception occurs intermittently

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a file using InputStreams and TransferManager something like this has to be done:

```java
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setContentLength(file.length());
TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
        .withS3Client(s3Instance())
        .withMinimumUploadPartSize(5 * 1024 * 1024) // min size for non-final multipart chunks is 5MB
        .withMultipartUploadThreshold(10 * 1024 * 1024) // set any threshold for multipart , using 10MB as example
        .build();

try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    Upload upload = transferManager.upload(bucketName, key, inputStream, objectMetadata);
    UploadResult uploadResult = upload.waitForUploadResult();
    // do more stuff...
}
```

Use try-with-resources in order to open and close the file input stream properly.

Also bear in mind that chunk size for non-final fragments of multipart uploads must be >= 5MB in size (otherwise the aws API may reject the fragment).

ContentLength is recommended to be specified in the ObjectMetadata to upload InputStreams with TransferManager.

Hope this helps